# how to iterate over list and append dictionary to another list

Tags: python, dictionary

```
lst = ['12233223','13232423','23453443']
```

i'm looking output like this:

```
new_list = [{'id':'12233223', 'new_id':'d2233223'},{'id':'13232423','new_id':'d3232423'}]
```

but I'm getting this

```
[{'id':13453443,'new_id':13453443},{'id':13453443,'new_id':13453443}]
```

Here is my code

```
lst = [{'id':'12233223'},{'id':'13232423',} {'id':'23453443'}]
d={}
new_list=[]
for each in lst:
    d['id']= each
    if len(each)==8 and each[0]==1:
    new_id = each.replace('1','d',1)
    d['new_id'] = new_id
    new_list.append(d)
```

Comment: You're appending the same dictionary each time through the loop. Move `d={}` inside the loop.

Comment: Your `lst` in the code is a list of dictionaries, shouldn't it be a list of strings?

Comment: @Bramar. Thanks so much. I've mode the d={} inside loop and it worked for me. thank you once again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this simpler version. Instead, the replace you can simply add `'d'` to the `string[1:]` -

```
[{'id':i,'new_id':'d'+i[1:]} for i in lst]
```

```
[{'id': '12233223', 'new_id': 'd2233223'},
 {'id': '13232423', 'new_id': 'd3232423'},
 {'id': '23453443', 'new_id': 'd3453443'}]
```

---

**EDIT:** just saw your `if` condition. Update with that -

```
[{'id':i,'new_id':'d'+i[1:]} for i in lst if i[0] if i[0]=='1' and len(i)==8]
```

```
[{'id': '12233223', 'new_id': 'd2233223'},
 {'id': '13232423', 'new_id': 'd3232423'}]
```